# Prevent AOP proxying of some classes

Tags: spring, proxy, spring-security, aop

Can AOP proxying be prevented for certain classes?

For instance when using `global-method-security` from Spring Security. In this case I want most beans with annotations to be proxied. But for some beans I am already using a custom proxy with certain special semantics.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is not a simple way to do it.

I see two options:

- Extends `SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource` and override `findAttributes()` method. Then   disable `secured-annotation` and enable your own `SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource` with the `metadata-source-ref` attribute. (Is simpler but work only with spring security)
- Other (more generic) way is overriding  the `shouldSkip()` method of `AbstractAutoProxyCreator` and set your own `AutoproxyCreator` in a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` using the `setBeanClassName()` method on the bean definition registered by Spring Security, ie `AopConfigUtils.AUTO_PROXY_CREATOR_BEAN_NAME`. For this approach you need to take care about what implementation of `AutoProxyCreator` are you finally using (`InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator`, `AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` or `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator`)

Comment: Have there been any improvements/changes regarding this since the question was asked first?